# Cant use apt because of gnome-settings-daemon

Tags: apt, gnome, dpkg, dependencies

i am running ubuntu gnome. when i attempt to do ANYTHING (update, upgrade, purge, remove, install...) with apt, i get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-control-center : Depends: gnome-settings-daemon (>= 3.25.90) but 3.24.0-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
                        Recommends: gnome-online-accounts (>= 3.25.3) but 3.24.0-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
                        Recommends: rygel but it is not going to be installed or
                                    rygel-tracker but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

then when i use

```
sudo apt-get --fix-broken install
```

i get:

```
Preparing to unpack .../gnome-settings-daemon_3.26.2-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gnome-settings-daemon (3.26.2-1) over (3.24.0-0ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/gnome-settings-daemon_3.26.2-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/lib/udev/rules.d/61-gnome-settings-daemon-rfkill.rules', which is also in package gnome-settings-daemon-schemas 3.24.0-0ubuntu2
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Reinstalling /etc/xdg/autostart/org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.XRANDR.desktop that was moved away
Reinstalling /etc/xdg/autostart/org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Orientation.desktop that was moved away
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/gnome-settings-daemon_3.26.2-1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I cannot do anything unless i am using dpkg to install a local package. can anybody help?

Comment: You will have to file a bug report

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it.
it was a problem with my repositories -- i had added the kali repository for the tools, and it was trying to install kali's gnome over ubuntu's gnome. it is all good!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about what you did. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)